# How to check if a value under condition is within an interval under other condition in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame of the following type:

```
Time    Behavior   Status
16.403  FOR    START
26.425  FOR    STOP
26.426  NI     START
28.460  NI     STOP
28.461  FOR    START
29.480  TSp    POINT
31.298  FOR    STOP
31.299  NI     START
33.297  NI     STOP
33.298  FOR    START
34.798  FOR    STOP
```

....

NI and FOR are lasting behaviour: Begin at the Time indicated by START in Status row, and end at STOP. TSp is a point event. 
The Behavior TSp can appear several times. I need to check if it is included in an interval of time defined by a FOR behavior.

I have tried several technics with differents loops, but I fail to code properly.. The format of the output is not important, could be True/False vector, or a number or anything else.

If someone could help I would be very grateful !!

Comment: Hi! What is the desired output in your example? Update your question with this info.

Comment: the format is not important actually, if I have juste a number it is fine, anything else is good as well (i have other transformations after this). =)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `data.table` approach

It uses a rolling join to create the FOR-intervals, and the a non-equi join to find POINTS within these FOR-intervals.

**sample data**

```
df <- fread('
Time    Behavior   Status
16.403  FOR    START
26.425  FOR    STOP
26.426  NI     START
28.460  NI     STOP
28.461  FOR    START
29.480  TSp    POINT
31.298  FOR    STOP
31.299  NI     START
33.297  NI     STOP
33.298  FOR    START
34.798  FOR    STOP
', key = "Time" )
```

**code**

```
#create FOR-intervals using a rolling join on FOR-START and FOR-STOP
forInterval <- df[ Behavior == "FOR" & Status == "START", ][
  df[ Behavior == "FOR" & Status == "STOP", ], 
  endTime := i.Time, roll = TRUE 
  ]

#      Time Behavior Status endTime
# 1: 16.403      FOR  START  26.425
# 2: 28.461      FOR  START  31.298
# 3: 33.298      FOR  START  34.798

#check if yout Tsp is within a forInterval using a non-equi join
df[Behavior == "TSp", ][forInterval, 
                        inside_FOR := paste0( i.Time, "-", i.endTime ), 
                        on = .(Time >= Time, Time <= endTime)][]
```

**output**

```
#     Time Behavior Status    inside_FOR
# 1: 29.48      TSp  POINT 28.461-31.298
```

Answer (score 1):

Give each interval an ID and cast to wide form based on `Status`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, id := (1 + (rowid(Behavior) - 1) %/% 2)*(Status != 'POINT')]

ints <- dcast(df[Status != 'POINT'], Behavior + id ~ Status, value.var = 'Time')

ints
#    Behavior id  START   STOP
# 1:      FOR  1 16.403 26.425
# 2:      FOR  2 28.461 31.298
# 3:      FOR  3 33.298 34.798
# 4:       NI  1 26.426 28.460
# 5:       NI  2 31.299 33.297
```

Option 1: Add extra columns to `ints` showing corresponding points

```
ints[df[Status == 'POINT'], on = .(START < Time, STOP > Time),
     `:=`(Point_Behavior = i.Behavior, Point_Time = i.Time)]
#    Behavior id  START   STOP Point_Behavior Point_Time
# 1:      FOR  1 16.403 26.425           <NA>         NA
# 2:      FOR  2 28.461 31.298            TSp      29.48
# 3:      FOR  3 33.298 34.798           <NA>         NA
# 4:       NI  1 26.426 28.460           <NA>         NA
# 5:       NI  2 31.299 33.297           <NA>         NA
```

Option 2: Subset `df` to points only and show matching intervals

```
df[Status == 'POINT'][
  ints, on = .(Time > START, Time < STOP),
  `:=`(i.Behavior = i.Behavior, START = START, STOP = STOP, id = i.id)][]
#     Time Behavior Status id i.Behavior  START   STOP
# 1: 29.48      TSp  POINT  2        FOR 28.461 31.298
```

Data used

```
df <- fread('
Time    Behavior   Status
16.403  FOR    START
26.425  FOR    STOP
26.426  NI     START
28.460  NI     STOP
28.461  FOR    START
29.480  TSp    POINT
31.298  FOR    STOP
31.299  NI     START
33.297  NI     STOP
33.298  FOR    START
34.798  FOR    STOP
')
```